# I can run script with ./script but can't run with bash script/sh script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I do have a script file (not mine), I can't run it with `bash scriptname`, `sh scriptname`. But I can run with `./scriptname` Why?

Error;
`script: script: cannot execute binary file`

`file script` results;

`script: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=955f30dd67a923f14fa87139336f33cb0a23b3ad, not stripped`

Comment: See this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447356/how-to-find-the-difference-between-a-script-file-and-a-binary-file) to learn more about the difference between scripts and binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `file script` says clearly, it is **not** a script, but an executable binary file. So obviously you can't run it with `bash` or `sh`. You can only execute it directly. It is completely normal behavior for binary files.

Comment: *"You can only execute it directly"* - pedantically, they *could* also execute it with the interpreter indicated by the `file` command, i.e. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 script`